# What would you call someone who likes to make lists?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in, "I make lists for everything, I just really like list-making. I'm a _______"

listphile? There's got to be something better than that.

Comment: *Listophile* would be the correct formation if you coin the word. Some other neologisms  would be *listoholic* and *listomaniac*. You can find a few examples of these words in Google and Google Books.

Comment: Have you ever noticed people who always make lists are never listless?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: As Fozzy Bear would say:  "Wucka, wucka!" Don

Comment: What's wrong with "compulsive list maker"??

Comment: I’m organized.  I’m a list fanatic.  I’m a nutcase.  What would you like to say about yourself with this word?

Comment: "list-making fool."

Answer (score 1):

A *listmaker*.

> "Tell you the truth, it's even a little better for me if he goes. I mean, he's a middle-aged kid. When I signed up with the network he sat up all night figuring out the fringe benefits and the pension plan. And he started to make lists this year. Lists of everything; subway stops, underwear, what he's gonna do next week. If somebody doesn't watch out he'll start making lists of what he's gonna do next year and for the next ten years. Hey, suppose they put him with a whole family of **list makers**. I didn't spend six years with him so he should turn into a **list maker**. He'll learn to know everything before it happens, he'll learn to plan, he'll learn how to be one of the nice dead people. Are you listening?" -- [*A Thousand Clowns*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059798/quotes?item=qt1088071)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point the [cataloger](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cataloger) word, as a person that writes items into a catalog. Catalogs itself are lists (or sets) of items, often subdivided in different subsets of lists according to some specific criteria.